# maven version exception on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

When I execute "mvn --version" I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Maven version I installed is maven 3.3.3

My java version is:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

echo $PATH returns:

```
/Library/Maven/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

How to solve the problem of Maven?

Comment: Try to downgrade to the version 3.2

Comment: I checked echo $JAVA_HOME and found that java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode). Is it the reason?

Answer (score 1):

`$JAVA_HOME` should be pointing to 1.8.0_65 as in your case.

If you want it to permanently change the value of `JAVA_HOME`, you will have to add the command to your `~/.profile` file.  Below are instructions on how to accomplish this instead:

- Open up Terminal.app (Applications → Utilities → Terminal)
- Type:

  ```
  emacs .profile
  ```
- Add this to the end of the .profile file:

  ```
  JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
  export JAVA_HOME;
  ```

  Note that `JAVA_HOME` should be the path of your JDK directory.
- Save and exit emacs (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>; <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>)
- Open a new Terminal window (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>) and type:

  ```
  $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
  ```